# Quotient space about identity component

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology

Let $T=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ be the circle group, $\mathscr A=C(T)$ be set of continuous function on $T$. $G(\mathscr A)$ denote set of invertible elements in $\mathscr A$, $G_{0}(\mathscr A)$ denote identity component (connected component which contain identity element) of $G(\mathscr A)$. My question is how to determine quotient space $G(\mathscr A)/G_{0}(\mathscr A)$? Is that equal to integer group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is isomorphic to the group of integers.

This is a special case of the Proposition in Yvonne Yuen, [Groups of invertible elements of Banach algebras](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1973-13102-7), Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 79 (1973), 82-84.

In general, if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $\mathscr{A}$ is the algebra of continuous functions on $X$ then that proposition establishes in particular $G(\mathscr{A})/G_0(\mathscr{A}) \cong [X,\mathbb{C}^\times] \cong [X, T]$ where $[X,Y]$ is the set of homotopy classes of maps $X \to Y$. Specializing to the case $X = T$ we get $[X,T] = [T,T] = \pi_1(T) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

The point is that $G_0(\mathscr{A})$ is path-connected and that a path in $G_0(\mathscr{A})$ is the same thing as a homotopy between maps $X \to \mathbb{C}^\times$. This shows that $G/G_0 = [X,\mathbb{C}^\times]$. Moreover, $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is homotopy equivalent to $T$ so that $[X,\mathbb{C}^\times] \cong [X,T]$.