# the group of homotopy class of complex valued maps

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology

My question is exactly the one here [Quotient space about identity component](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374885/quotient-space-about-identity-component/374993#374993)
but I can't get the answer!
actually it's better to say that I feel there is something wrong in my understanding of the the question!
could you please explain about it? Does the word "component" in the question refer to the largest connected set or the path component? I used to think that we should prove the quotient space is isomorphic to that homotopy class, but the answer seems different!

http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1973-79-01/S0002-9904-1973-13102-7/home.html
says that f and g are homotopic if and only if $fg^{-1}\in G_{0}$

why?

Comment: The set in question is open in a locally path connected space, so connected and path-connected mean the same there.

Comment: You should tell us what exactly in the answer you don't understand.

Comment: It says:the point is that $G_0(A)$ is path-connected and that a path in $G_0(A)$ is the same thing as a homotopy between maps $X\to \mathbb{C}^\times$  I can't understand how it leads us to the desired result? I feel there should be something about the structure!